# How to insert multiple JSON files into postgresql table at a time?

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql, data-migration

I have multiple JSON files, they all have same format but the values are different based on each transaction. I want to migrate this data to a postgresql table. What is the best way to proceed with this?

Right now, I am using the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (MULTIPROCESS VARCHAR(20), HTTP_REFERER VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO TEST SELECT MULTIPROCESS, HTTP_REFERER FROM json_populate_record(NULL::test, '{"multiprocess": true,"http_referer": "http://localhost:9000/"}');
```

But, once the number of files become large, it becomes very difficult to use this technique. Is there any other way to do this effectively?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [LATERAL JOIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions/) to do insert more than one row at a time:

```
 WITH 
  json AS(
   VALUES('{"multiprocess": true,"http_referer":"http://localhost:9000"}')
     ,('{"multiprocess": false,"http_referer": "http://localhost:9001/"}')
     ,('{"multiprocess": true,"http_referer": "http://localhost:9002/"}')
) INSERT INTO test 
   SELECT multiprocess, http_referer 
   FROM   json, LATERAL json_populate_record(NULL::test, json.column1::json);
```

Or you could insert into a staging table first and then populate your other table.