# Adding multiple JSON objects into Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a json file containing hundreds of Json objects.

My postgresql table was created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE collections(
 id serial,
 collection json);
```

It can add one object at a time into the table using `INSERT INTO collections (collection) values (json_object);` but that's tedious and not sustainable. What would be a better way to do this?

One solution I found (as [explained by this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129526/loading-json-data-from-a-file-into-postgres?noredirect=1&lq=1)) was to create (1) create temporary table and bulk json data into it (2) create columns corresponding to keys and add values like so:

```
    create temporary table temp_json (values text) on commit drop;
copy temp_json from 'C:\SAMPLE.JSON';

-- remove this comment to insert records into your table
-- insert into tbl_staging_eventlog1 ("EId", "Category", "Mac", "Path", "ID") 

select values->>'EId' as EId,
       values->>'Category' as Category,
       values->>'Mac' as Mac,
       values->>'Path' as Path,
       values->>'ID' as ID      
from   (
           select json_array_elements(replace(values,'\','\\')::json) as values 
           from   temp_json
       ) a;
```

but this defeats the whole purpose of NoSQL. I merely just want to store an autoincrementing id with a json object on each row.

Comment: Does it fits your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/q/29497662/3937028

Comment: @antonio_antuan not really, I have one JSON file with objects like this `[{json_object1}, {json_object2},.....]` and I want to add them to my postgresql db as `row1: 1, json_object2  row2: 2 , json_object2..` keep in mind these are hundreds of json objects and increasing, otherwise I would ve continued doing it by hand.

Comment: Oh, ok, try to use this: http://adpgtech.blogspot.ru/2014/09/importing-json-data.html?m=1

Comment: Which operating system are you on? Do you have something like Python you can call from a command line? It can be done with a few typed lines, but they'll be system-specific.

Comment: @Feneric I am windows 7 entreprise. I was definitely thinking about using python. I am in the process of writing a script right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it in Python with the [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/) package if anyone is interested. just make sure to fill in the appropriate fields(database, username, password, etc..)

```
import psycopg2
import json


path_to_file = input('Enter path to json file:')
with open(path_to_file, 'r') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

collection_array = []
for item in data:
    collection_array.append(json.dumps(item))



try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="", user="", password="",host="127.0.0.1",port="5433")
    print ("opened  database successfully")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    for element in collection_array:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO my_table (json_column_name) VALUES (%s)", (element,))
    print("successfully inserted records")    


except psycopg2.Error as e:
    raise

finally:
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    print("connection is closed")
```

Comment: Cool, you beat me to it. That's very close though to what I was going to recommend.

Comment: @Feneric haha yea I decided to take a crack at it; wasn't  hard at all especially with the awesome psycopg2 package.